# Get an object from one function to another

Tags: php, arrays

I got a function who gets all the labels out of the database and puts them into an array, but if I take the object to another function it will be NULL

```
private static $labels='blaat';

public function loadDatabaseLabels(){
    $res=DB::query("SELECT * FROM labels");
    $label_array=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $label_array[$row['indicator']]=$row['text'];
    }
    $labels = new label();
    $labels->labels=$label_array;
}

public function getLabel($indicator){
    var_dump($labels->label);
}
```

Comment: Pass $labels as an argument to getLabel() else it won't be in scope.... this really is a PHP 101 question - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues here.  First, `$labels` is declared `private static` - this means to access it you would do so using `self::$labels`:

```
// set like this:
self::$labels->labels = $labels_array;

public function getLabel($indicator){
    var_dump(self::$labels->label);
}
```

Secondly, you are not setting `self::$lables->label`, but `self::$labels->labels` (note the plural *labels*).  So in the above function, `var_dump` is accessing something that hasn't been set.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a code snippet from a PHP class. If you set a variable as `$labels` it's in the local method scope, is not seen by anything outside the method and gets lost after method finishes.

To set variables on the object instance, use `$this->labels = ...` and `var_dump($this->labels)`, or as it's declared static, `self::$labels`, instead.

If that's not the case then forget about `static public private` keywords. Functions would still not see anything outside of them tho, so you have an ugly option of adding `global $labels` in front of the methods (karma will get back at you for this) or passing `$labels` bu reference to both methods as `&$labels`.

Comment: if i use a this i get this error:
Using $this when not in object context in

Comment: declaring a function as `public` implies that it exists within a class - otherwise you are using `static`, `public`, etc incorrectly.